Dynamic Programming with Finite Horizon, Different Ranges of Parameters
A dynamic programming exercise in homework.
Consider the following problem, where $R$ and $b$ are given, and solve for $ \{ 
 c_t,A_{t+1} \} _{t=0}^T $. $$ \max_{\{c_t,A_{t+1}\}_{t=0}^T} \sum_{t=0}^T \beta^t c_t(b-c_t) \quad s.t. \quad A_{t+1}=R(A_t-c_t). $$
$A_0$ is given and $ \{c_t\}_{t=0}^T, \{A_{t+1}\}_{t=0}^T $ are non-negative.
I can get the Euler equation that $$ b-2c_t=\beta R(b-2c_{t+1}), $$ and that $$ b-2(A_t-\frac{1}{R}A_{t+1}=\beta R[b-2(A_{t+1}-\frac{1}{R}A_{t+2})] $$
Note that there're no ranges for parameters. So I'm a little confused about the transversality condition. For example, the relationship between $A_t$ and $\frac{b}{2}$. I think different ranges of the parameters may yield totally different outcomes, but I wanna a complete solution as much as possible. Can somebody help me out. Great thanks!
